# \multiinclude: How to specify animation frame for handout mode?

Tags: beamer

I am including an animation using

```
\multiinclude[<visible@+>][graphics={height=\paperheight},format=png]{path/to/animation}};
```

Is there a simple way to specify that I would like to get only the last frame (or a specific frame) in handout mode?

(The output *looks* good in handout mode, but I know that the frames are put on top of each other, which is technically ugly and makes the rendering slow.)

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
\mode<beamer>{\multiinclude[<visible@+>][graphics={height=\paperheight},format=png]{path/to/animation}}
\mode<handout>{\multiinclude[start=xx][graphics={height=\paperheight},format=png]{path/to/animation}}
```

where you need to replace xx by the number of pngs in this animation.